# Why to use Tuple over Set in Scala?

Tags: scala, set, tuples, difference

Both can store mixed types but a Set seems far more powerful since it features union, intersection or diff among other.

Another important difference is that tuples aren't considered collections.

I'm learning Scala and I'm wondering why would I want to use tuples over sets.

Comment: Set removes duplicates whereas Tuples can have duplicates

Comment: That's a good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main advantage of tuples is that type information is maintained.  This is a big deal in a statically typed language like Scala.

```
scala> (4.2,'c',true,"blah",7)
res2: (Double, Char, Boolean, String, Int) = (4.2,c,true,blah,7)

scala> Set(4.2,'c',true,"blah",7)
<console>:11: warning: a type was inferred to be `Any`; this may indicate a programming error.
       Set(4.2,'c',true,"blah",7)
           ^
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Any] = Set(true, blah, 7, c, 4.2)
```

Once our `Set` type is `Set[Any]` then we've lost type information that could be valuable in avoiding problems (i.e. bugs) down the line.

Also, pulling elements from a `Set[Any]` can be a pain.  Every element extracted from it [e.g. `mySet.head`] will probably have to be tested for type before it can be used. Getting individual elements from a tuple can also be rather cumbersome [`myTup._3`] but the compiler, and the rest of your code, knows exactly what it's getting.

Answer (score 3):

Sets:

- Must all be the same type.
- Cannot contain duplicate elements.
- Do not preserve insertion order.
- Can be very large, with varying size.
- Have more collection-like operations.

Tuples:

- Can contain different types.
- Can be verified at compile time.
- Can only contain 22 elements.
- Are intended to hold temporary results with a static size.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't use something like a Set when you need a Tuple. Imagine writing a method but instead of returning just an Int, for example, you need to return two Ints, or an Int and a String. Returning a Set[Any] doesn't really make sense there, but returning an (Int, Int) or (Int, String) is a lot more readable and clear in terms of intent.

Comment: I agree. There is literally zero overlap between sets and tuples. They have so little in common with each other that it doesn't even make sense to ask about differences between them, just like it doesn't make sense to ask about the difference between the color blue and an attack helicopter.

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't make sense to ask such a silly question if you know the answer before hand as per your experience, not my case I'm sorry.

Comment: No worries, Alejandro, and no need to apologize :)

Answer (score 1):

A Set is iterable collection that can be either mutable or immutable and can only take distinct values.

```
val set = Set('a','b','b')
println(set)
set.foreach(i => print(i + ", "))
```

Will print

```
Set(a,b)
a, b,
```

A Tuple is immutable, and it is not a collection, and it will not reduce elements to distinct values and it maintains the types of the elements. It can be iterable if you apply the productIterator() method to the tuple.

```
val tuple = ('a','b','b')
println(tuple)
tuple.productIterator.foreach(i => println(i))
```

Will print

```
(a,b,b)
a, b, b,
```

A tuple is limited by 22 elements where a Set does not have that limit.

```
val set = Set('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')
println("set: " + set)
```

Will print `set: Set(e, s, x, n, j, y, t, u, f, a, m, i, v, q, b, g, l, p, c, h, r, w, k, o, z, d)`

A Set is arguably more robust while a tuple provides some surface level flexibility that a Set (and other collections) don't provide. Here is a graphic of some scala collections other than Set.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One huge difference between a set and a tuple, is that a set is viewed as a collection as if we took it out of [*Set Theory*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory).
 A `Set` can be used for efficiently intersecting, unions, diffing and also viewing if another set is a subset/superset of the other. There is no meaning to a duplicate elements in a set, as there may always be a representation of an element.

A `TupleN` simply represents a container of N elements, and doesn't posses any of the properties that such a `Set` holds. Thus, you'd want to use it when you want to holds multiple items in a "bag", whereas a set would be used when you want to view multiple items as a group and operate on them accordingly.